# Gradle STS project giving Server Redirected too many times(20)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

While Creating new **Gradle project** it is giving **server Redirected too many times(20)**

**Why it may be happening? 
What can be done ?**

[image]

Project Creation:-

Create Gradle STS Project - > Name and specified Sample Project as JavaQuickstart

Comment: Can you provide us with your Gradle please?

Comment: Is there an error in the error log?

Comment: @Kris no their is no error

Comment: @MrGracket i dont understand what you need?

Comment: Is this happening when you are creating the project or building it? If is the second option provide us with your build.Gradle so we can see what is happening

Comment: @MrGracket its while creating the project.

Comment: @omkomawar Could you provide us a step-to-step guide of what are you doing here, so we can see the error two

Comment: @MrGracket please check the updates in the question.. Thank You.

Comment: @omkomawar it seems to be a problem of the repo where is the Javaquickstart, try to create a different Gradle STS project and see what happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122719/discussion-between-om-komawar-and-mrgracket).